# Making an application bundle open a file

Tags: finder, applications

I have a very simple Mac application bundle which is basically a wrapper around Spyder. I am trying to get it to open .py files.

Here is the entirety of the application directory

```
.
./Contents
./Contents/MacOS
./Contents/MacOS/Spyder
./Contents/Info.plist
```

Here is `Info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Spyder</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Spyder</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And here is `Spyder`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Launching Spyder with file: $@" > /tmp/spyderlog
source ~/.profile
/Users/mike/.scripts/launch-spyder "$@" >> /tmp/spyderlog
```

Unfortunately, if I try to use this application to open some .py file, it doesn't look like the filename is passed into my Spyder executable at all: $@ is always blank.

How on Earth do you get Finder to send the filename into the executable?